# finding special elements in an array

Tags: python, arrays, indices

I have  such an array:

```
    x = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
```

I want to find elements bigger than 3. I am trying:

```
     ppoc = np.zeros((3,3))

     ixu = np.argwhere(x > 2)
     ppoc = ppoc[0, ixu]
```

But the problem is ppoc is a 2*2 array, but I need to return an array with the same size as x, which the rest of the elements are zero.

ppoc must look like:

ppoc = [[0,0], [3,4], [5,6]]

Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

Comment: You never defined `ppoc` in the first place... And what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do. It would help if you explicitly told us what `ppoc` is and what your expected result is.

Comment: You can't maintain multidimensionality when filtering an array because you cannot guarantee that the array will not become ragged. Best you can do is return a boolean array where that condition is true. As soon as you use that mask to select the items though, you lose the dimensionality. Note that `np.argwhere` returns a tuple of index arrays, each corresponding to the original array's axes.

Comment: Please read about how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your question  is very unclear, but to get all value greater than 3
`print("Values bigger than 10 =", x[x>3])`

Answer (score 2):

You can vectorize the computation that sends `t` to `0` or `t` depending on if `t < 3`, then apply this vectorized function to `x`:

```
np.vectorize(lambda t: 0 if t < 3 else t)(x)
```

this evaluates to:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you want to replace every element in the array by 0 if it's smaller than 3.
Here's the answer :

```
x = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
ppoc = x * (x > 2)

Output :
array([[0, 0],
   [3, 4],
   [5, 6]])
```

Is this what you wanted ?